# Doxygen declares class as a function

Tags: php, doxygen

I dont know wether its a bug or my fault but i have 3 classes

```
class system {
    function archive() { "has nothing to do with class archive" }
}

class archive extends system {

}

class theme extends system {
   $archive = new archive( "gets documented as core::archive() instead of class archive" );
}
```

In `class::system` there is a function called `archive()`. When i create an instance of `class::archive` inside of `class::theme` Doxygen document it as the `function::archive()` from `class::core`.

[image]

I think its because there is a function with that name but how can i resolve this so that the documentation is correct? Is renaming an (and the only) solution?

Greets

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using ? As far as I can see it in the current version of doxygen (1.8.14) is is OK. Maybe I'm missing something, in this case please be a bit more explicit in the question of what you do see  and expect.

Comment: I use version 1.8.14. I expect that the call of `$archive = new archive()` would be documented as a usage of CLASS archive, not the function archive inside of CLASS core with the same name.

Comment: Just for clarity: The line `$archive = new archive( "gets documented as core::archive() instead of class archive" );` should read `$archive = new archive( "gets documented as system::archive() instead of class archive" );`?

Comment: When looking at the documentation of `class theme`all links look OK to me. Which changes did you make to the default doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)? I only set some `EXTRACT`...`to `YES`.

Comment: Please create a small example that signalizes the problem, the given reference is just the output (and a bit large) and not really suitable to find the problem.

Comment: I added a picture, maybe it helps you. If not, nevermind i deceided to rename the function anyway.